# Login function always end up being false

Tags: php, authentication

For some reason this bit of code...

```
if(empty($_POST) === false) {

#$username = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']));
#$password = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']));

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and a password';
} else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
    # code...
    $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered?';
} else {
    $login = login($username,$password);
    if($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect.';
    } else {
        die($login);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}

output_errors($errors);

}
```

And here are the functions.. Not sure what is going on exactly here to make it not be true. Granted that I am learning about `mysqli_*` extensions still, but the logic makes sense to me. It's just weird.

```
function user_id_from_username($username) {
$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","lr");
$username = sanitize($username);
return mysqli_data_seek(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0);
mysqli_close($conn);
}

function login($username,$password) {
  $conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","lr");

  $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);

  $username = sanitize($username);
  $password = md5($password);

return (mysqli_data_seek(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;

#return (mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT count('id') FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'") === 1) ? $user_id : false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `mysqli_connect` in *each* of your functions?

Comment: What is happening& What is the error?

Comment: Also, *please, please, please* don't nect `mysqli_*` calls like that.  It makes error checking impossible and is not helpful.

Comment: What is `sanitize()`, why are you not using parameterised queries instead?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything,  as well as `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`

Comment: Because it was the way I got it to use the $conn variable in each function. I could probably just make it a global variable but just wanted to get the login to work.

Comment: The thing is is the only error I see is the one I made the "That username/password combination is incorrect., "

Comment: Why do you need to run *multiple* queries to just log the user in?  Why not just run one?  P.S. `md5` isn't safe for passwords.

Comment: Well the user_id_from_username function is meant to let me login the user in with their id vs username. I had it working with logging in as username. The problem with that is that when I wrote the functionality to let the user change their name it messed up the session. Sorry about any confusion. P.S. I know md5 isn't the most secure and I should use (sha1?) but for now it will work just for local use.

Comment: Okay. So I got the login to work again by commenting out the

#$user_id = user_id_from_username($username); line. 
However now it doesn't show the user_data. 

i.e 
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  $session_username = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $user_data = user_data($session_username, 'id','username','first_name','last_name','password','email','profile_picture');
 }

Answer (score 1):

Mysqli_data_seek returns **true or false** and sets a pointer on the mysql result resource to the desired offset.

Refer to the PHP manual on how to use these functions.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php